# How to calculate center of mass of a hollow hemi-sphere with some thickness?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, integration

[image]

When we calculate Center of mass (COM) of a hollow sphere, we assume that it's thickness is
infinitesimally small, but in real world, we do not have any object with zero thickness, so how can we calculate COM of a hollow sphere with inner radius of $r$, and outer radius of $R$, which can be seen in the image.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DKBGsorVYqfo&ved=2ahUKEwjAoO773rDrAhV94zgGHazKBucQFjABegQIFhAK&usg=AOvVaw3oUKyi8KUmU6CWc64sFeMm might help

Answer (score 4):

If you know the center of mass of a half sphere you are done: the center of mass of the hollow hemi-sphere is the center of mass of two concentric half spheres one with negative mass.

Comment: Interesting you formulate it as negative mass. I would just subtract the part that you've added to much. But that's semantics.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is more appropriate to think of the center of charge...

Comment: However it is just semantic ragrading the mass. The fact that this procedure for the center of mass leads to the right result is based on the linearity (convexity) properties of the center of mass and, even if it is quite natural, it should be proved. (The proof is very easy actually.)

Comment: For this approach it is just the same as splitting up the integral (r to R = 0 to R - (0 to r)

Comment: Sure, it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spherical coordinates, where the element of volume $dV=\rho^2 \sin\theta d\rho d\theta d\varphi$, use the formula for the $z$-coordinate of the center of mass (remember that $z=\rho\cos\theta$) and calculate the 3d integrals.

Comment: thank you for all your answers, but can anyone give me a final answer. I am still very confused

Comment: @HarshAgarwal : I am not supposed to give a complete solution to a homework-like question, sorry.

Comment: @HarshAgarwal Please read the homework-policy. I think you're supposed to explain everything you did, and where you are stuck.